# What is the default unit of weight of a product

Tags: magento, units-of-measurement

What is the default unit of weight of a product in Magento?

For example, when I update a product in Magento it asks the weight of the product and the actual weight of product is 350 grams but I don't know how to write Grams as unit or what is the by default weight unit of Magento so I will convert the weight in that unit and then write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no default unit of weight on Magento, just a decimal value.

You can set the value 350 (as being 350 grams). The weight is especially important in your shipping table rates. [Magento explanation of Product fields](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/product-general-information)

Edit: As Fiasco Labs explains, you get to decide your standard unit of weight (In the US they use pounds, in Europe they use kilos). When you create your shipping tables, you will get the chance to add the shipping price based on the total weight sent out, and the unit of weight should be the same across your app.

Comment: Basically, the default weight is 1.0 of whatever your Shipping Methods have been reconciled to choose as their base weight. So, 1 Lb. or 1 kg.